# Restrict Spark job in local mode

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Is there any way to restrict access to execute spark-submit with spark deploy mode as local mode. If I permit users to execute jobs in local mode my yarn cluster will become under utilized.

I have configured to use yarn as cluster manager to schedule spark jobs.
I have checked spark configs where I did not find any parameters to allow only a specific deploy mode. User can override the default deploy mode while submitting spark jobs to the cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can incentivize and facilitate using YARN by setting the `spark.master` key to `yarn` in your `conf/spark-defaults.conf` file. If your configuration is ready to point to the proper master, by default users will deploy their jobs on YARN.

I'm not aware of any way to completely bar your users from using a master, especially if it's under their control (as it's the case for `local`). What you can do, if you control the Spark installation, is modifying the existing `spark-shell`/`spark-submit` launch script to detect if a user is trying to explicitly use `local` as a master and preventing this to happen. Alternatively you could also have your own script that checks and prevents any `local` session to be opened and then runs `spark-shell`/`spark-submit` normally.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Right now I have scheduled a script whenever any spark process which uses local as spark master, it will kill the process.

Comment: So there is no direct configuration available in spark to restrict a specific deploy mode.

Comment: I set spark.master=yarn in my spark-defaults.conf in my cluster.